# Vue.js hello world won't render

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create an Hello world app like in the get started documentation on the Vue.js site. Everything looks fine but the text isn't displayed on the page, just the html code.

Vue version : 1.0.26

Here's the html code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Vue!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      {{message}}
    </div>
    <script src="vue.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></scrip>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's the app.js code :

```html
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
});
```

Of course, vue.js is the vue.js source file and both js files are loaded.

No errors in the console

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Was the missing `t` the problem? Does it work once you included it?

Comment: it fixed the problem with static html.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> <script src="app.js"></scrip>
> ```

You have a typo. The `t` is missing from your end tag. Consequently the `app.js` script will never load.

Methods that might have detected this:

- Look at the Developer Tools Network tab in your browser. You won't see the request for `app.js`
- [Validate](http://validator.w3.org/nu/) your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know - the `data` prop of a `Vue` component should be a `function` that returns an `Object`

`data () {  return {  message: 'Hello vue....'  }  }`

see: [Vue JS Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function)